# How can I make a waiting icon appear in the middle of my page with twitter bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I looked through all the documentation but still cannot find an example. What I would like to do is to have a waiting icon appear in my page when it's doing an Ajax call. Can someone tell me how I can do this with twitter bootstrap.

Also if there are any other non-jquery implementations which are better I would also like to know about those.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pick an [loading icon](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/#examples) **(gif)** from font-awesome for bootstrap,

1. show before the ajax call
2. hide once the ajax response is delivered

To position the icon in the middle of the screen, use the following [css](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/)

```
.ajaxLoader {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   margin-top: -250px; /* Half the height */
   margin-left: -250px; /* Half the width */
}
```

1. Also take a look for [button loading images](http://msurguy.github.io/ladda-bootstrap/)
2. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVHbV/177/)

Comment: Woahhh, as good as this is definitely don't apply that css to the IMG tag... otherwise that's the rest of your images broken. Use something like .ajax-loader and apply that class to the image.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough yup right.  Since OP haven't mentioned any html I didn't cared much.  Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want something dead center, you can use the absolute position technique.

To do it, create a div and give it these attributes:

```
margin:auto;
position:absolute;
top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;
width:<however wide the image is>;
height:<however big the image is>;
```

This will put it smack bam in the center no matter when someone resizes the screen, making it work on mobiles as well as desktops (as long as the image isn't huge).

If you want this to work inside another div, make sure that the parent is `position:relative;`

Answer (score 0):

- You can add a bootstrapmodal with your waiting logo,
- unbind theclose event,
- and close the modal when your ajax call is ended...